# ¿Cómo hacer un programa que me diga que NO hay un registro con el nombre suministrado por el usuario, en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Verán, tengo un programa que se conecta con MySQL. Si tú coges y escribes ''Juan'' en la opción de Filtro por Nombre, te muestra en una tabla todos los registros con el nombre ''Juan'', pero cuando pongo un nombre con el cual no hay registros en dicha tabla, aparece vacía.

Lo que quiero es un mensaje que me diga ''No hay ningún registro con ese nombre.''

Gracias de antemano.

```
<?php

@$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];

?>

<?php if ($nombre){ 
?>
<div = "content"><table border = "1"><h1>
    <tr>
        <td>Cedula</td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Apellido</td>
        <td>Compania</td>
        <td>Posicion</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Telefono</td>
        <td>Notas</td>
    </tr>
<?php

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bdempresa") or
    die("Problemas con la conexión");

$registro = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT cedula, nombre, apellido, 
compania, posicion, email, telefono, notas FROM `contactos` WHERE `nombre` 
LIKE '$nombre'")
or die("Este es el error: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

mysqli_close($conexion);

echo "<h3><u>A continuacion se muestran los datos filtrados por nombre.</h3> 
</u>";
while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($registro)){

?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['cedula'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['nombre'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['apellido'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['compania'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['posicion'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['email'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['telefono'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['notas'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php }}
 ?>

</table>
</div></h1>
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el codigo con el que se crea esa funcion de mostrar los nombres para poder ayudarte, asi con lo que pones es imposible porque seria especular

Comment: Hola estimado Stephen, bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Para poder ayudarte, coloca tu código donde realizas la consulta de los registros y así podemos precisar más con lo que necesitas apoyo.

Comment: Listo ahí está el código.

Comment: Proba lo siguiente, agrega esta linea antes del while  var_dump(count($registro));  ya que $registro es el array que se forma con la info que te devuelve la consulta eso te tendria que devolver un numero mayor a 0 si hay registros con los parametros del filtro que le pasas y 0 si no hay nadie, si eso funciona es solo cuestion de un if si count($registro) es > a 0 mostra lo datos si no mostra un mensaje "No hay registros que cumplan con los parametros consultados" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

que tal si probas el siguiente código:

```
<?php

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];


if(!empty($nombre))
{
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bdempresa")
                                or die("Problemas con la conexión");

    $registro = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT cedula, nombre, apellido,
                                        compania, posicion, email, telefono, notas FROM `contactos` WHERE `nombre` LIKE '$nombre'")
                                        or die("Este es el error: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    $mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($registro);

    if($mostrar == null)
    {
        ?>
        <h3><u>No hay ningún registro con ese nombre</u></h3>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <div = "content"><table border = "1"><h1>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedula</td>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Apellido</td>
                <td>Compania</td>
                <td>Posicion</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Telefono</td>
                <td>Notas</td>
            </tr>
        <?php

        echo "<h3><u>A continuacion se muestran los datos filtrados por nombre.</h3> </u>";

        do
        {
            ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['cedula'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['nombre'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['apellido'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['compania'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['posicion'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['email'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['telefono'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['notas'] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($registro));
        ?>
        </table>
        </div></h1>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```